# Processing CSV files with Metadata in S3 bucket in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a CSV file that goes something like this:

```
Report Name: Stackoverflow parse data
Date of Report: 31 October, 2022

Col1, Col2, Col3,...
Data, Data, Data, ...
```

The values before Headers, essentially data that states what the CSV is for and when it was created (can contain multiple values, hence has dynamic number of rows), need to be removed from the CSV so I can parse it in Pentaho. Now, the CSV files are on an S3 bucket and I am fetching them using `S3 CSV Input` but I am not sure how to proceed with filtering the non-required data so I can successfully parse the CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the complete file as a CSV with only one column, adding the rownumber to the output. Then you apply a filter to get rid of the first n rows, and then you use the **Split fields** step to separate the rows into columns.

You'll need more steps to transform numbers and dates into the correct format (using the Split fields you'll get strings), and maybe more operations to preformat some other columns.

Or you could create a temporal copy of with your S3 CSV file without the first n rows, and read that file instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: In the Csv input, just adding rownumber
[image]

Step2:Use filter
[image]

Step3:Add a output component like csv or database.